# Issues with React Hook Form Radio Buttons in Child Components

Tags: radio-button, react-props, react-hook-form

I have a React application where I've structured my form with a parent component containing two child components. Each child component includes various inputs, and I'm passing the register and errors props from React Hook Form to these child components. While the text inputs work as expected, I'm encountering issues specifically with radio buttons. The radio buttons function correctly when the form is placed in the parent component, but they exhibit unexpected behavior when the form is moved to a child component. What could be causing this discrepancy?

Parent Component

```
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import Button from "../../components/common/Button";
import LoginSignupButton from "../../components/common/LoginSignupButton";
import EventCreator from "../../components/events/EventCreator";
import EventDescription from "../../components/events/EventDescription";

const CreateEvent = () => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();

  function handleCreateEventSubmit(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }

  return (
    <div className="h-full bg-mercury">
      <LoginSignupButton isLogin={true} />
      <Button
        styleclass={"bg-bluePurple rounded-full text-white"}
        name={"Go Back"}
      />
      <h1 className="text-4xl text-center rounded">CreateEvent</h1>
      <form
        className="h-screen overflow-auto"
        onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleCreateEventSubmit)}
      >
        <EventCreator register={register} errors={errors} />
        <EventDescription register={register} errors={errors} />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CreateEvent;
```

Child-1 -->[EventCreator]
I have only included the input - radio
Tried with input:text and worked Fine

```
<div className="grid grid-cols-1   md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-5 gap-1 ">
          <div className="flex items-center ps-4 bg-white  rounded text-sm ">
            <input
              {...register("radio")}
              type="radio"
              id="celebratory-club"
              value="celebratory-club"
              className="w-4 h-4 text-blue-600 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300  "
            />
            <label
              htmlFor="celebratory-club"
              className="w-full py-4 ms-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 "
            >
              Celebratory Club
            </label>
          </div>
          <div className="flex items-center ps-4 bg-white  rounded ">
            <input
              {...register("radio")}
              type="radio"
              id="technical-club"
              value="technical-club"
              className="w-4 h-4 text-blue-600 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300 "
            />
            <label
              htmlFor="technical-club"
              className="w-full py-4 ms-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 "
            >
              Technical Club
            </label>
          </div>
          <div className="flex items-center ps-4 bg-white  rounded ">
            <input
              {...register("radio")}
              id="artmusic-club"
              type="radio"
              value="artmusic-club"
              className="w-4 h-4 text-blue-600 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300 "
            />
            <label
              htmlFor="artmusic-club"
              className="w-full py-4 ms-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 "
            >
              Art & Music Club
            </label>
          </div>
          <div className="flex items-center ps-4 bg-white  rounded ">
            <input
              {...register("radio")}
              id="sports-club"
              type="radio"
              value="sports-club"
              className="w-4 h-4 text-blue-600 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300 "
            />
            <label
              htmlFor="sports-club"
              className="w-full py-4 ms-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 "
            >
              Sports Club
            </label>
          </div>
          <div className="flex items-center ps-4 bg-white  rounded ">
            <input
              {...register("radio")}
              id="dance-club"
              type="radio"
              value="dance-club"
              className="w-4 h-4 text-blue-600 bg-gray-100 border-gray-300 "
            />
            <label
              htmlFor="dance-club"
              className="w-full py-4 ms-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 "
            >
              Dance Club
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
```